# git pull request and remote branch relation

Tags: git

I git cloned master from the server. Then create a local new_branch, make changes and add/commit to local new_branch. Then push new_branch to server.

Until this time, I can't see this new_branch on a server by git branch -r.
Added: I can't see the new_branch on git server browser either. The master is not under my control. In my understanding, after I "git push origin new_branch", the local new_branch should be created on remote already. I thought creating new_branch on the remote should have nothing to do with creating a pull request or not. However, even no commit detail in a log, as my colleague said. He told me to create a pull request(on the browser) to begin a review, then merge to master.

I don't understand this process very well. Why creating a new remote branch is bonded to creating a pull request? Or is that just a pre-defined binding by the project admin to enforce the review process? Anyway, I can't see the remote new_branch after push. I have Read/Write permission.

The toolsRT_lingyuntest(the new_branch mentioned) is what I pushed to the remote. I searched the red list(not show fully in this snapshot). I can't find it.

(I have to erase some texts in the picture to hide some information) 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just after you pushed the new branch to remote, your local repo is not yet aware of the new remote branch, only the local one.

You'd now have to `git fetch` to have your newly created branch appear in `git branch -r` output.

---

For the pull request part, hard to say from here, but it's likely just an indication of the prefered way to merge things into `master`, as it is often the case for "main" (stable) branches.

So to put on `master` whatever changes you commited and pushed on your new branch, you'll have to create, on remote server, the pull request `new_branch > master`

Comment: I can't see it even on server browser side or after using git fetch. Is there a setting by the master admin to control the process?

Comment: @Wason What did the remote output back when you pushed `new_branch` from your local? Did it succeed?

Comment: I added the screen shot. I think it succeeded. the toolsRT_lingyuntest is what I pushed to the remote. I searched the red list. I can't find it.

Comment: @Wason No, it's clearly failed, and git hints at a solution :-) "fatal: the current branch xyz has no upstream..."

Comment: Will it fail even I didn't have any modification after creating the new branch?

Comment: @Wason Yes, this is not a problem with the ref you're trying to push, but with git not knowing *where* you want to push it. Look up "git setting upstream for a branch" for details but the above hint is basically the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. It's my fault.

I didn't use "-u" on first push. That seems why I got "fatal: the current branch xyz has no upstream"

I missed rest of the red list actually. It didn't show complete list and I didn't type space bar to read the rest. My branch is there, though I don't know when it's created.

During the operation, Actually I had tried once "git push -u origin xyz" but I'm unaware I had changed my current path to another git repo folder. And I got an error I can't understand. Every step returned me an error and I lose patience.

Now I got why. Several mixed mistakes.

The process is:

1. create local branch
2. make changes, add, commit
3. git push -u origin xyz , clearly know where you're

Then should see the remote branch.
I think the "make pull request" is another thing, irrespective to the new branch. It's a next optional step to make review and merge code automatically. Am I right?